# look up a time if it falls within a time range and return the corresponding value in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Still trying to learn Pandas. Let's assume a dataframe includes start and end of an event for an even-type and the event's Val. Here is an example:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({ 'start': ["11:00","13:00", "14:00"], 'end': ["12:00","14:00", "15:00"], 'event_type':[1,2,3], 'Val':['a','b','c']})
>>> df['start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start'])
>>> df['end'] = pd.to_datetime(df['end'])
>>> df
                Start                 End  event_type Val
0 2021-03-05 11:00:00 2021-03-05 12:00:00           1   a
1 2021-03-05 13:00:00 2021-03-05 14:00:00           2   b
2 2021-03-05 14:00:00 2021-03-05 15:00:00           3   c
```

What is the best way for example to find a corresponding value for an event that starts at `11:10` and ends `11:30` of event_type `1`, in the Val column. For instance, for this event example, since start and end times fall withing the first row of the df, it should return `a`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays`

```
df.index = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(left = df.start, right = df.end)
```

Out put like below

```
df.loc['11:30']
Out[73]: 
start         2021-03-05 11:00:00
end           2021-03-05 12:00:00
event_type                      1
Val                             a
Name: (2021-03-05 11:00:00, 2021-03-05 12:00:00], dtype: object

df.loc['11:30','Val']
Out[75]: 'a'
```